# Can I see who forked a now-closed public repo?

Tags: git, github, repository, git-fork

I'm using a Dart package based on a public github repo that has recently been closed.  In looking at the google cache of the page I can see it was forked 58 times before going off to the great `git reset --hard` in the sky:
 [image: screen capture]

Does anyone know how I can find who forked it, so that I can possibly access a recent copy of the source code?

Answer (score 1):

Deleting a public repository
When you delete a public repository, one of the existing public forks is chosen to be the new parent repository. All other repositories are forked off of this new parent and subsequent pull requests go to this new parent.

source: https://help.github.com/en/articles/what-happens-to-forks-when-a-repository-is-deleted-or-changes-visibility

hope this helps you find it.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that too, however it doesn't say how to find the forked repos?

Comment: Well I tried searching for "fluttery" in the Repo search in Github and then I looked for the one with the similar amounts of forks as the screenshot you got and I found this: 
https://github.com/miguelramosfdz/fluttery/network/members
I know this is not really an official way to find it, but I feel like it would always work if you know what the Repo name is.